# Joomla 2.5 - retrieving categories list in order like in Category Manager

Tags: php, joomla, categories

After googling and messing around for 2 days i've come to the dead end looking for a rescuer. :-)
I want to get the categories just like in the same order they appear in Category Manager in Joomla backend.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "select * from #__categories where extension='com_content' and title!='Uncategorised' order by parent_id,title,lft";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
$hm = $db->getNumRows();
$rows = $db->loadRowList();
```

I insert the values in a DDL but there is some mess with their order. Any suggestion, please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just order by `lft`. This is how it's done in the category manager in the backend :-).
See /administrator/components/com_categories/models/categories.php

Comment: T-H-A-N-K Y-O-U. I don't understand why, but it works!
-a php beginner.-